# About Ice Assassin (Frostburn) spell

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

The Simulacrum spell has the following description:
You can't create a simulacrum of a creature whose HD or levels exceed twice your caster level.

Is also the spell of Ice Assassin (Frostburn) the same?

If not, can I duplicate any powerful creature?

And, Ice Assassin has all the memories of the original creature and is entirely under the control of the creator.

By making an ice assassin, can I hear any information the original creature has without worrying about being resisted?

Comment: The spell *ice assassin* is extremely controversial and carries with it a lot of baggage. With that in mind, could this question be broken into two questions, this one being *How powerful of a creature can a caster create using the* ice assassin *spell?* and another being *What connection does the caster of the* ice assassin *spell have to his creation?* (Such a split will also allow this question to have a more precise title, too!)